# Ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot installation with Windows 10 not showing any partitions

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, boot-partition

I have a Dell 8910 with a 2 TB HDD. It came pre loaded with Windows 10. I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot from a usb. I disabled secure boot, etc. and shrunk the partition before starting the installation from usb.

However, it goes straight from the language screen to the partition screen, and it does not show the screen where it asks if you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager. The partition screen is empty. How do I make this installation work?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GX69.jpg)

Comment: Do you know if your Windows installation is UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: It has UEFI. It also says something like Legacy option rom 'enabled'